# Building dice combinations, in a list by tuple

Tags: python

Need to write a function called build_all_dice_pairs that generates tuples that represent all permutations of two dice throws. I must use a single comprehension to solve this.

Below is some of the certain code I have trying to pass the test:

```
def build_all_dice_pairs():
  dice_values = []
  dice = tuple(n for n in range(1,7))
  dice2 = tuple(i for i in range(1,7))
  print(dice)
  print(dice2)
  dice_values.append(dice)
  dice_values.append(dice2)
  print(dice_values)

  return
```

Comment: You have to use a single comprehension to solve this because it is homework?

Comment: Yes that is necessary

Comment: I would suggest learning more about comprehensions rather than getting homework answers from SO. For example this is a good overview: https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html

Comment: `list(itertools.product(dice,dice2))`

Comment: Forget comprehensions for a moment. Try and solve the problem using regular loops and `.append`. You will need two for loops.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single list iteration vs multiple list comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44666215/single-list-iteration-vs-multiple-list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 1):

**The question isn't clear, but Try this may help you:**

```
from itertools import product

myList = list(product(range(1,7), repeat=2)) # the second argument can be however
                                            # many die you want to roll.
print (myList)
```

**The result:**

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though your question is not clear. Still, so far what I have understood is that you need all possible combinations of two dice. Here is a better and simple solution:

def build_all_dice_pairs():

```
dice = tuple(n for n in range(1,7))

dice_values = []

for x in dice:
    for y in dice:
        dice_values.append([x,y])

# print(dice_values)
return dice_values
```

formated_values = build_all_dice_pairs()
print(formated_values)

You can also watch my 2 minutes video to understand how this code works ... 
https://youtu.be/NtG0mrNc3_k