# Multiple list comprehension vs single for loop

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I am trying to understand the best practices of coding in python. I have a pandas dataframe for which I need to work on the columns that contains strings or floats, I am doing basic data management and I was wondering is it possible that a single for loop is faster than many list comprehensions.

In my case the target dataframe is 4mln or more lines and I'd have like 10 list comprehensions so speed is important and I have to decide whether to write it inside the for loop or many list comprehensions. Do you have suggestions?

```
for i in range(dataframe.shape[0]):
        try: #Price dummy
            if dataframe["Price"].iloc[i]=="0":
                dataframe["Price_Dummy"].iloc[i] = 0
            else:
                dataframe["Price_Dummy"].iloc[i] = 1
        except:
            pass
        try: #Transform everything in MB (middle unit)
            unit_of_measure = dataframe["Size"].iloc[i].split(" ")[-1].lower()
            size = float(dataframe["Size"].iloc[i].split(" ")[0])
            if unit_of_measure =="kb":
                dataframe["Size"].iloc[i] = size/1000
            elif unit_of_measure =="gb":
                dataframe["Size"].iloc[i] = size*1000
            else:
                dataframe["Size"].iloc[i] = size
        except:
            pass
```

(other 10+ operations)

vs

the same in list comprehension

I have found this link: [Single list iteration vs multiple list comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44666215/single-list-iteration-vs-multiple-list-comprehensions)

yet this doesn't say whether list comprehensions are always faster independently from the number of iterations considered

Comment: List comprehensions are only "syntactic sugar" - they don't have any performance advantages when compared to a loop

Comment: @Mortz that is not completely right. That synctactic sugar is exactly what makes them more efficient when used specifically to build lists, since the `append` function doesn't need to be loaded and used. Otherwise, yeah, they're not better than a for loop.

Speaking of the question, isn't there a way to do what you intend with pandas? I'm pretty sure that that would be even faster than for loops or lists comprehensions.

Comment: List comprehensions are o̵n̵l̵y̵ largely "syntactic sugar" - they don't have a̶n̶y̶ much performance advantages when compared to a loop, but can have a negative impact on readability if used recklessly

Comment: The only best practice you should be worried about is to avoid iterating over a DataFrames / Series. It's pretty slow, and definitely should be the bottleneck here. At least use `apply` row-wise. Although it's not ideal, should be a bit of improvement.

Comment: You are modifying a `dataframe`, not a `list`: If ever possible, this should be done using native Pandas methods (which tend to be vectorized), and not looping over the rows (see @Hein's answer for an example).

Comment: Ok thank you for that, where I lack knowledge I tend to overcomplicate things and build my own solution. I will try to look into the pandas documentation more accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try it without a loop using `np.where` clauses for the if-elif-else combinations. That's usually pretty fast.

```py
import numpy as np

# dataframe is a DataFrame containing data
# Now this:

dataframe["Price"] = np.where(dataframe["Price_Dummy"] == "0",0,1)

# String operations work on whole string columns as well
unit_of_measure = dataframe["Size"].str.split(" ", expand=True)[1].lower()

size = dataframe["Size"].str.split(" ", expand=True)[0].astype("float")

kb_case = np.where(unit_of_measure =="kb", size/1000, size)
dataframe["Size"] = np.where(unit_of_measure =="gb", size*1000, kb_case)
```

Notice that I replaced the `[-1]` in the `unit_of_measure =` line with `[1]` as the `expand=True` option does not support the `-1` indexing. So you would have to know at which position your unit ends up.

Information on splitting strings in DataFrames can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html).

In the last two lines, I reproduced the if-elif-else combination which you kind of have to create from the bottom up: Your final result `dataframe["Size"]` equals `size*1000` if the unit is `gb`. If not, it equals the `kb_case` which includes the case where the unit is `kb` as well as all other cases.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think you switched "Price_Dummy" with "Price" but overall pretty useful. Additionally I get that "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'" so I guess I'll have to use re.sub() before

Comment: Tried it out for a while with the other operations, works wonderfully accepted answer

Comment: Hey there, glad I could help! Thanks for mentioning the flaw with lower()!